# ASP.Net incorrect background image style rendered

Tags: asp.net, css, background-image

Using ASP.Net, I have a server control for which i would like to add the inline css style "background-image:none".  However, when i call:

```
writer.AddStyleAttribute("background-image", "none");
```

The following inline style is generated (and tries to resolve the url "none"):

```
background-image:url(none)
```

Is there a special syntax I can use to set the background image to none inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code for the `HTMLTextWriter` and `CssTextWriter` classes in .NET Reflector, the only thing I can think of is subclassing `HTMLTextWriter` yourself.

"Binary not the first element in the style enum", `~HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor`, is what it uses for any style whose name it doesn't recognize, and therefore doesn't bother to check if the value needs wrapped in "url()" when it's actually written out.

`HtmlTextWriterEx` isn't the greatest name, but whatever. Depending on what you're doing, you might(?) need to do something like this in your code-behind `System.Web.UI.Page` subclass:

```
protected override HtmlTextWriter CreateHtmlTextWriter(TextWriter writer)
{
    return new HtmlTextWriterEx(writer);
}
```

And here's the class:

```
class HtmlTextWriterEx : HtmlTextWriter
{
    public HtmlTextWriterEx(TextWriter writer) 
        : this(writer, "\t")
    {
    }

    public HtmlTextWriterEx(TextWriter writer, string tabString)
        : base(writer, tabString)
    {

    }

    public override void AddStyleAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        if (name.ToLower() == "background-image" && value.ToLower() == "none")
            base.AddStyleAttribute(name, value, ~HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor);
        else
            base.AddStyleAttribute(name, value);
    }

    public override void AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle key, string value)
    {
        if(key == HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundImage && value.ToLower() == "none")
            base.AddStyleAttribute("background-image", value, ~HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor);
        else
            base.AddStyleAttribute(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a CSS class to your page such as

```
.noimage { background-image: none; }
```

Then instead of adding the style attribute in your code behind you could add the CssClass.