# Changing background image in ASP.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio

Im currently trying to design a webpage, I have set the background image to a image in my website folder. The asp.net code shows up as:

body background="ProtectedPages/Storage/green.png"

I was wondering if there was a way to change this with a button, using c# code. I am trying to make it so the user of the website can change the background image from a list of options, any help would be appreciated:)

Cheers, John.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530784/asp-net-incorrect-background-image-style-rendered

Comment: Yes, it's not difficult to do. What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Well pull out the images from storage and present it to him, when he selects one, point up the background to that resource, Where have you got stuck ?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using asp.net, I just want it to change the image the background is pointed at, change the path kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

change your body tag as below

body id="bdy1" runat="server"

now change your .aspx.cs page

write the following on page load

1) If you want image background then

bdy1.Attributes.Add("style", "background:url(images/tulips.jpg);");

2) if you want color as background then

bdy1.Attributes.Add("style", "background:teal");

Answer (score 1):

for changing background dynamically you need to do as below.

place dropdown and button in aspx page  as below.

```
<input type="button" value="Change BG" onclick="ChangeBG();" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem>bg_1.jpg</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>bg_2.jpg</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>bg_3.jpg</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>bg_4.jpg</asp:ListItem>        
</asp:DropDownList>
```

define javascript function as below in head section

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    function ChangeBG() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("DropDownList1");
        var strimg = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        document.body.background = strimg;
    }
</script>
```

then most important call ChangeBG() function on load event of body.

```
<body onload="ChangeBG();"  >
```

you can also set background on dropdown change event.

Hope this will helps you..happy coding....